# Weird behaviour of System.out.println in java

Tags: java

```
class Foo {}
class Boo extends Foo {}

public class Tester {
 public static void main(String[]args) {
 Foo f = new Foo();
 Boo b = new Boo();
 System.out.println("****"+f==b+"****");//line 1
 boolean flag = f==b;
 System.out.println("****"+flag+"****");//line 2
 }
}
```

For line1 output is `false`
For line2 output is `****false****` 
For line 2 it is concatenating properly.

**My question** is why for line 1 it is printing just the value and not the proper output with stars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` operand has higher precedence than `==` (which makes sense when you want to compare mathematical expressions), so `"****"+f==b+"****"` is the same as `("****"+f)==(b+"****")`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have the two lines be identical you should change "line 1" to:

```
System.out.println("****"+(f==b)+"****");
```

The parentheses will provide the necessary precedence.

You said that "line 2 is concatenating properly". Actually line 1 is concatenating properly too (as far as Java is concerned). What you have for line 1 can be broken down as follows:

```
String tmp1 = "****" + f;  // ****Foo@56f0474c
String tmp2 = b + "****";  // Boo@6d15a113****
System.out.println(tmp1 == tmp2); // Are the two String instances equivalent?
```

As can be seen above, the concatenations result in new strings and their instances are compared for equality. The final result "false" makes perfect sense then.